# First button click does not change text but updates the database

Tags: java, button, textchanged

As the title says, the text doesn't change on the first click but the database update runs and changes the value. However, for every succeeding clicks, it works as expected, albeit the values are now just reversed.

I have tried mixing up the order of my statements but to no avail.

Here is my code

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import entity.Settings;

public class GradeViewController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        // Load the GradeView entity (assuming you have an ID for it)
        Settings gradeView = session.get(Settings.class, 0);

        if (gradeView.getStatus()== 0) {
            btnGradeView.setText("Enable Grade Viewing");
            gradeView.setStatus(0);
        } else {
            btnGradeView.setText("Disable Grade Viewing");
            gradeView.setStatus(1);
        }
    }    

    private void setGradeViewToggle() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            // Load the GradeView entity (assuming you have an ID for it)
            Settings gradeView = session.get(Settings.class, 0);

            if (gradeView.getStatus()== 0) {
                // Set the "status" to 1 to enable
                gradeView.setStatus(1);
                btnGradeView.setText("Enable Grade Viewing");
            } else {
                // Set the "status" to 0 to disable
                gradeView.setStatus(0);
                btnGradeView.setText("Disable Grade Viewing");
            }

            // Persist the changes to the database
            session.update(gradeView);

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle any exceptions
        } finally {
            session.close();
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
     }
    
    @FXML
    private void actionSetGradeViewToggle(ActionEvent event) {
        setGradeViewToggle();
    }
}
```

I have tried mixing up the order of the statements.
I was expecting that the button works on the first click, changing the text on the first click.

Answer (score -2):

In your initialize method, you set the button text based on the gradeView.getStatus() value, which is retrieved from the database. If this is the case, you should ensure that the initial state of your database (gradeView.getStatus()) is correctly set before the initialize method is called.To make sure the button and the database state are in sync on the first click, you should double-check the initial value of gradeView.getStatus() in your database. If it's not working as expected, it might be due to the initial data in your database.Also, you can add some debug print statements to check the initial value of gradeView.getStatus() in your initialize method to help diagnose the issue.Here's how you can add a debug statement:
`System.out.println("Initial gradeView.getStatus(): " + gradeView.getStatus());` 
This will help you verify that the initial state of your button and the database value are consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by "make sure the button and the database state are in sync on the first click". It checks the status first before displaying anything. I have tried checking the database and comparing what is in the output and they match. But it is always on the first click that the text doesn't change but the status does.

Comment: Nevermind, my mind was just dumb and exhausted that time, i just realized my mistake. The text should say disable for the if statement instead and enable for the else. Thanks though.